# Should mapreduce map a line of a text file and then reduce or process a whole text file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running a Mapreduce job on 50k text docs 1-100 "pages" long. I don't perform much on the doc, just a few regex processes. It takes like 7 hours to MapReduce.

The mapper function runs on a line of text, basically the map function is called for every line of text in every document, that's a lot of processes. Then the reducer runs and combines the data.

```
public class TextMetricsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
      @Override
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = value.toString();
…
```

Since I'm reading small text files, it seems like most of my processing time is probably spent in calling mappers. I mean if 1 of the 50,000 files has 5,000 lines that's 5,000 map process just for that one file.

How would I change a mapper to just read in the whole file? I really want to see the whole doc in the mapper at once to create the statistics I need.

*I have to use Hadoop due to business requirements.

Comment: It's not 5,000 map processes for the one file - it will call the `map(...)` method many times within the same instance of `TextMetricsMapper`.

Comment: Is there a way I can get a hold of the whole text file? Like a setting that says "Don't break up and process line by line, grab the whole file." The map function seems to automatically grab each line.

Comment: Sure, you can write a custom InputFormat.